# Node Red output as JSON via HTTP

Tags: json, node-red

I want to call node red HTTP page, like **node_red_url:1880/test** and have a json formatted output back, like:

```
{"result": [{"Type": "Temp","Data": "30.0 C","id": "31"}]}
```

Data will be pulled from a MQTT node

is this possible?
Ive found a static page, but i cant to find out how to add dynamic data to it
https://cookbook.nodered.org/http/serve-json-content.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's perfectly possible. You just have to realise that the MQTT delivery has to be totally separate from the HTTP request.

MQTT-in -> function node to store latest value in the [context](http://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions#storing-data)

HTTP In -> function node to retrieve value from context -> HTTP Response node

Comment: Why not try first, you can always update the question with what you've tried and somebody will help you fix it.